# Laravel 5 - Can't route to controller

Tags: laravel

I'm having an issue routing in laravel 5. My code is:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return "Ok";
});

//Authentication Routes
Route::post("/authenticate", "AuthenticationController@Authenticate");
Route::post("/register", "AuthenticationController@Register");
```

If i place the inline functions, it all works well, however when I try the controller way, it just outputs a blank page.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here's the controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use User;
use Auth;
use Input;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;


class AuthenticationController extends BaseController
{
    public function Authenticate() {
        if(Auth::attempt([  'email'=>Input::get('email'), 
                            'password'=>Input::get('password')]))
        {
            return response()->json("OK");
        } 
        else 
        {
            return response()->json("ERROR");
        }

    }

    public function Register() {    
        return response()->json("Not Implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm could it be the namespace i wonder... (Nope it doesn't seem to be)

Comment: enable debug true.check is it thowing any error

Comment: Debug is set to true already. No error. Tried die('something') at the beginning of the function too, no effect. I'm pretty sure it doesn't get excuted for some reason.

Comment: Check you error log. Also, method names should be camelCase (i.e. not begin with a capital letter).

Comment: Nothing in the error log, and camelCasing my methods doesn't change anything (nor should it, i believe i should be free to pick my preffered casing format) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're extending the wrong Controller here:

`use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`

Also set in your `.env` file `debug=true` to see what the Error is.

Probably is controller related issue.

You should extend the Controller within your `app\Http\Controllers\` folder. (which falls within the same namespace). Especially to get `ValidatesRequests` trait working (really useful!).

Fix your controller by removing the:

`use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`

Example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function Authenticate() {
        if(Auth::attempt([  'email'=>Input::get('email'), 
                            'password'=>Input::get('password')]))
        {
            return response()->json("OK");
        } 
        else 
        {
            return response()->json("ERROR");
        }

    }

    public function Register() {    
        return response()->json("Not Implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny thing. I was enabling debug in the app/config/app.php file, not in the .env file... There was an error somewhere else, but i'd only get a blank screen and a 500 response (which i didn't notice because i assumed that in case of error there would be an error). Works now. Thanks. I'll also look into that other controller, sounds interesting.                                 Hey guys let's make a framework - but get this - we'll have 1000 base controllers and the user can extend whichever they want!

Comment: I believe the controller within the `app/Http/Controllers/` folder is put to give an example how you can generalize your app and put common tasks in it.

Comment: Aah, that one. Sorry, i thought there was another alternative base controller in the framework. A bit tired heh.

Comment: You can extend `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` too. Depends on what your app is. offtopic: I was a huge fan of Laravel when version 3 came out. Later I started working for a company which was using Zend and I hadnt had the time to follow Laravel's development. Now I'm again back on track AND EVERYTHING LOOKS LIKE A ROCKET SCIENCE. :D

Comment: Yeah, i know the feeling. I've been using 4 for a while, and took a 2 month break on a native project, and now 5 came out and it's quite changed, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has already been answered and accepted, but I thought it a good idea to share something else and I cannot comment yet.

The unresponsive controller can also be caused when adding extra methods inside a resource controller, now there's not a problem in doing that, however.

If adding routes to your route file and you have a resource route setup for that controller, make sure you either:

A: Add the extra routes above the declaration of your resource route.
B: Use a two stroke approach i.e. task/ajax/getGoodStuff

This is because is you do a php artisan route:list you will notice your resource routes have (using the task controller as example):

task/{task} three time for methods head, patch and delete and
task/{task}/edit for editing a record.

Now this will only drive you crazy while the other methods are not completed, but it will drive you crazy at some point!